# When I set webpage background color to black(#000000) in my CSS file it appears white on web browser, why is this?

Tags: html, css, colors, hex

```
body {
background-color: #000000
text-align:center;
}
#main {
    width: 1000;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: #f1c83e;
}
```

When I set my background-color to black in my CSS code why does my background appear as white in my browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a semicolon at the end of `background-color: #000000` so that it is `background-color: #000000;`, your code will work properly.

Here is a fiddle of your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/81rfa9bu/

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

#main {
  width: 1000;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #f1c83e;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div id="main">
    Hi
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding semicolon at the end, for background-color property?

```
background-color: #000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot put the ; in the final of the line

```
background-color: #000000;
```